# Error in starting oracle 18c express editiom

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

I have little problem with starting oracle 18c express edition, when I tried to startup, it wrote me the error    ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info

```
SQL> startup force mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1073741352 bytes
Fixed Size                  8797736 bytes
Variable Size             687865856 bytes
Database Buffers          373293056 bytes
Redo Buffers                3784704 bytes
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

Can someone give me a point how to solve this error?

When I try to run show parametres, it return to me:

```
show parameter control_files

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
control_files                        string      C:\APP\UZIVATEL\PRODUCT\18.0.0
                                                 \DBHOMEXE\DATABASE\CONTROL01.C
                                                 TL
```

I tryed to set ctrl files to `alter system set control_files='C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin' scope =spfile;`

but it still have a problem

```
SQL> startup force mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1073741352 bytes
Fixed Size                  8797736 bytes
Variable Size             687865856 bytes
Database Buffers          373293056 bytes
Redo Buffers                3784704 bytes
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

When I tried to create controlfile, there is this error:

```
    SQL> CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "ORCL" NORESETLOGS NOARCHIVELOG
      2      MAXLOGFILES 32
      3      MAXLOGMEMBERS 2
      4      MAXDATAFILES 32
      5      MAXINSTANCES 1
      6      MAXLOGHISTORY 449
      7  LOGFILE
      8    GROUP 1 'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database\t_log1.f'  SIZE 500K,
      9    GROUP 2 'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database/t_log2.f'  SIZE 500K
     10  # STANDBY LOGFILE
    SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "STANDBY LO..." - rest of line ignored.
     10  DATAFILE
     11    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database/dbs/t_db1.f',
     12    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database/dbs/dbu19i.dbf',
     13    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database/tbs_11.f',
     14    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\databasedbs/smundo.dbf',
     15    '/C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\databasedemo.dbf'
     16  CHARACTER SET WE8DEC;
    CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "ORCL" NORESETLOGS NOARCHIVELOG
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
    ORA-01565: error in identifying file
    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database/dbs/t_db1.f'
    ORA-27047: unable to read the header block of file
    OSD-04006: ReadFile() failure, unable to read from file
    O/S-Error: (OS 234) Jsou k┐dispozici dal┐┐ data.

I create file C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\database/dbs/t_db1.f, but without sucess.

If I try to create controll file, then there is an error :

SQL> CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "ORCL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
  2      MAXLOGFILES 16
  3      MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
  4      MAXDATAFILES 1024
  5      MAXINSTANCES 8
  6      MAXLOGHISTORY 292
  7  LOGFILE
  8    GROUP 1 'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\REDO01.LOG'  SIZE 200M BLOCKSIZE 512,
  9    GROUP 2 'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\\XE\REDO02.LOG'  SIZE 200M BLOCKSIZE 512,
 10    GROUP 3 'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\\XE\REDO03.LOG'  SIZE 200M BLOCKSIZE 512
 11  -- STANDBY LOGFILE
 12  DATAFILE
 13    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\SYSTEM01.DBF',
 14    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\SYSAUX01.DBF',
 15    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\UNDOTBS01.DBF',
 16    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\PDBSEED\SYSTEM01.DBF',
 17    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\PDBSEED\SYSAUX01.DBF',
 18    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\USERS01.DBF',
 19    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\PDBSEED\UNDOTBS01.DBF',
 20    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\XEPDB1\SYSTEM01.DBF',
 21    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\XEPDB1\SYSAUX01.DBF',
 22    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\XEPDB1\UNDOTBS01.DBF',
 23    'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\XE\XEPDB1\USERS01.DBF'
 24  CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8 --verify your character set;
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "ORCL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
ORA-01565: error in identifying file
'C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\oradata\SYSTEM01.DBF'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) Syst┐m nem┐┐e nal┐zt uveden┐ soubor.
```

Note I havent any .dbf files in oracle instalation.

Comment: `startup nomount` `show parameter controlfile` where is it looking? Is that correct? What did you do between it working and now?

Comment: show parameter controlfile display nothing

Comment: My mistake, parameter is called control_files so try that

Comment: It returns SQL> show parameter control_files

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
control_files                        string      C:\APP\UZIVATEL\PRODUCT\18.0.0
                                                 \DBHOMEXE\DATABASE\CONTROL01.C
                                                 TL

Comment: There’s white space in the file extension, you’ll need to remove that. Double check the rest of that path is correct. You can fix with `alter system set control_files='<path>' scope =spfile;` and restart (or fix your pfile in a text editor and restart)

Comment: i add more info in my question.

Comment: The parameter needs to be set to the complete path to the control file.